Difficulty exporting from Google Earth Engine to GeoTIFF, results are NoData
I am trying to do some image processing and export the results from Google Earth Engine to a GeoTIFF I can open in ArcGIS. I am able to run this code and generate an image that is visible in GEE (see below)

The result is exported to GDrive as a GeoTIFF, but when I load it in ArcGIS, nothing is displayed and anywhere I click shows "NoData". When I open the raster properties in ArcGIS, I see this information. Notably it shows 1 column and 20038 rows.

Is there something wrong with my export code? Do I need to reproject this image for it to export to a usable format?
Working code here:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/ff194ab9c211ddc78bb2430a9ce0fd38
Relevant for export:
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: snowCover_0401,
  description: 'SCA_20pct_'+year+'0401',
  folder: 'GEE',
  region: snowCover_0401.geometry(),
  crs: projection.crs, 
  maxPixels: 1e7,
  fileFormat: 'GEOTIFF'
});


You have a problem with the region property of your export. If you print out snowCover_0401.geometry(), you'll see that you didn't successfully clip your image. That's because geometry is not an ee.Geometry, but an ee.FeatureCollection.
All you have to do is to turn your geometry into an actual ee.Geometry by calling geometry() on it.
var geometry = ee.FeatureCollection("TIGER/2016/States")
  .filter(ee.Filter.stringStartsWith("NAME", "Colo"))
  .map(function(feature) {
    return feature.simplify(1000)
  })
  .geometry()

https://code.earthengine.google.com/0ff016b809b60156c51e480fb4c05463

This worked perfectly. Thank you
